# Бесконечный скролл

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Как сделать бесконечный скролл, чтобы новые картинки подгружались не в тогда, когда страница достигает конца, а где-то за 300-500px до ее конца, как в Вконтакте например.

Саму функцию получения постов через AJAX - писать не надо. Только как ее в нужное время вызвать

```
  window.addEventListener('scroll',function(e){
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset
    var distanseToDownLine = post.pageHeight - scrollTop - post.clientHeight
    if(distanseToDownLine < 300){
        post.add()
    }
},false)
```

Проблема в том, что post.add() вызывается несколько раз.

Comment: Еще можно привязать обработчик onScroll к объекту Window JS.

Comment: Чтобы postAdd не вызыался несколько раз, оберните его в timeout, а по успешному получению контента сделайте clearTimeout.

Можно обойтись только функцией success, которая будет блокировать до своего успешного вызова следующий запрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По событию [`mouseWheel`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189840/get-mouse-wheel-events-in-jquery) вызывать проверку [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/), сравнивая с [длиной страницы](http://api.jquery.com/height/). При разнице в `300-500px` вызываете свой `ajax`

Answer (score 0):

Вот небольшой [примерчик](http://jsbin.com/ilevux/16)