# Как сделать бесконечный scroll у div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, прокрутка

Пишу сайт, потребовалось сделать div с бесконечным скроллом без добавления HTML кода в div при скролле. Можно ли это сделать средствами CSS/JS?

Comment: Можно. Через JS.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar а как именно?

Comment: а что такое "бесконечный скролл"? У вас бесконечное количество контента?

Comment: @likel0vsky Какой вопрос, такой и ответ) Вообще вот тут уже дан ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/248618/

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Бесконечный скролл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/248618/%d0%91%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb)